# My Flink Streaming job execution finishes while the data source still produces data?

Tags: java, apache-flink

Hello I am new with Flink and currently trying to set-up a basic pipeline that:

- receives data from a random string generator,
- does a `wordCount`
- and saves the output to a file.

I am interested in ensuring the Flink programs keeps running until I decide to stop it manually, or when there are no input data anymore. However, the program starts and ends even while the input data is still being generated.

I have tried using either of these 2 windowing line of code but no success:

```
.window(ProcessingTimeSessionWindows.withGap(Time.minutes(10)))
.timeWindow(Time.of(2500, MILLISECONDS), Time.of(500, MILLISECONDS))
```

Below is an example of the input file which runs continuously:

```
ACBAB
CEECC
BCCAD
EADAE
BBCDA
DCADD
```

This is the code i am currently running:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        final ParameterTool params = ParameterTool.fromArgs(args);

        // set up the execution environment
        final StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();

        // get input data
        DataStream<String> text = null;
        if (params.has("input")) {
            // read the text file from given input path
            text = env.readTextFile(params.get("input"));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Executing WindowWordCount example with default input data set.");
            System.out.println("Use --input to specify file input.");
            // get default test text data
            text = env.fromElements("input");
        }

        // make parameters available in the web interface
        env.getConfig().setGlobalJobParameters(params);

       
        DataStream<Tuple2<String, Integer>> stream = 
            text.flatMap(new WindowWordCount.Tokenizer())
            .keyBy(0)
            .timeWindow(Time.of(2500, MILLISECONDS), Time.of(500, MILLISECONDS))
            .sum(1);

        // emit result
        if (params.has("output")) {
            stream.writeAsText(params.get("output"));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Printing result to stdout. Use --output to specify output path.");
            stream.print();
        }

        // execute program
        env.execute("WindowWordCount");
    }
    
  
    public static final class Tokenizer implements FlatMapFunction<String, Tuple2<String, Integer>> {

        @Override
        public void flatMap(String value, Collector<Tuple2<String, Integer>> out) {
            // normalize and split the line
            String[] tokens = value.toLowerCase().split("\\W+");

            // emit the pairs
            for (String token : tokens) {
                if (token.length() > 0) {
                    out.collect(new Tuple2<>(token, 1));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Programs runs fine and stops after a while with the following message:

> Starting execution of program
> Program execution finished
> Job with JobID 74a6f54d80af96f029a8e6c32d9bc8da has finished.
> Job Runtime: 176994 ms

What I want is for the program to keep running because I am interested in analyzing the performance metrics of the Flink engine.

Comment: when you read the end of file, the stream is closed. What is the purpose to keep the job running? There is no new data coming in.

Comment: @Snakienn, the idea is for the stream to keep running that is why the input file keeps growing. Indeed there is new data coming in.